# Do not call CanExecute methods from hidden windows

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I use MVVM pattern in my WPF application. I'm trying to cache my windows in order to increase performance. To do that I never close them and just hide instead of closing. All hidden windows are stored in a dictionary, so I can re-use them. When window is opened again I create  a new view model and associate it with a cached view.

But there is a problem with that because hidden window keep invoking of CanExecute methods of commands in ViewModels. This leads to performance issues when user opened and closed a lot of windows.

When I set `Window.DataContext` property to null or do `ClearValue(DataContextProperty)` I achieve my goal, but there is a problem with that. If I have any two way bindings, they all fired during unbinding from data context. So, some values in my view model become null. I do not want that because in some cases I read properties from ViewModels after hidding of Views.

Can you help me to resolve the main problem (do not call CanExecute methods from hidden windows).

Comment: Are you using RoutedCommands or your own custom ICommand implementation?

Comment: You aren't using your VMs correctly. When a view is closed (hidden), (eventually) the VM gets thrown out. You should restructure your code not to reference "hidden" VMs. Do whatever you need to do with the VM before the unbinding happens, then immediately dispose of it. Don't think of your cached views as hidden, think of them as closed, because that's what they really are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you get much control over when and where the `CommandManager` decides to fire off a `RequerySuggested` event.  One way you may be able to mitigate the performance hit would be to have a property on your ViewModel that allows you supress execution of `CanExecute`.  Whenever a View that a ViewModel is bound to goes into hiding, then you can set this property to **True**

**A simple example**

```
// Called when a view goes into hiding
myViewModel.SuppressCommandRequery = True
```

In your CanExecute handler(s) simply place this line at the beginning of the method

```
public bool CanExecuteCommand(Object parameter) {

    if (this.SuppressCommandRequery) 
        return;

    // Continue processing the event...
}
```

I would point out that you need to take special care to then disable the suppression whenever the view came out of hiding.  However, in the cases where re-displaying the View results in a new instance of the ViewModel this would not be necessary.

Alternatively, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506283/can-i-suppress-the-canexecute-call-within-the-mvvm-pattern?rq=1) which talks about using an implementation of a `DeletegateCommand` from the Prism MVVM Framework.  I haven't used this myself, but it looks like it may address some of your concerns.

Comment: I'm not sure why people hook their commands into the CommandManager.  Its a bit of cargo cult programming started by some of the earliest examples of ICommand implementations, I suppose.  People, if you don't know you *need* to do this, then don't!  I've created hundreds of commands without ever hooking them into the CommandManager and have never missed it.

Comment: You're probably right.  The only time I think that the CommandManager really becomes necessary is when your Command's ability to execute is dependant on something in the UI (such as the position of the mouse).  In that case, the command probably couldn't really be on your ViewModel without violating MVVM somehow.

Comment: Thanks, I will follow your advice and add a property to my view models. I have base classes for my viewmodels and views, so, it will be easy to hook hide events. Also, I will change the implementation of the base class for my commands in order to check this property before calling CanExecute methods.

Comment: @Will I absolutely agree with you. There is no sense to hook commands to CommandManager in my case. But the project was initially started by not very skilled developers and I need to fix it somehow without global refactorings.